# Where is file type mainp24f.c in MPLAB?

Tags: mplab, pic24

I have just started (again!) [Programming 16-bit Microcontrollers in C, Learning to Fly the PIC24](https://blog.flyingpic24.com/programming-16-bit/)

MPLAB has changed a bit since I last used it!

One of the first things I am meant to do is install the C30 or XC16 compiler.  I installed the XC16 compiler and shortly later I am instructed as follows:

> From the MPLAB X main menu, select: File> NewFile...
>
> 1. Choose File Type: in the categories panel, expand the Microchip Embedded folder and click on the C30 compiler.  In the file types panel select the mainp24f.c type.

The only option is `main.c`

I installed the C30 compiler from here (https://www.microchip.com/development-tools/downloads-archive) but still only see the `main.c` option.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you taking those instructions from?  The book you linked?  That book is 6 years old so it's very likely those instructions could be rendered out of date by new versions of the toolchains/IDE.

It doesn't actually matter what your .c file is called.  As long as you have a main() function to enter.  Using the "main.c" it gives you should be fine.

I would also recommend using XC16 if possible.  C30 is no longer updated and is now considered legacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book you linked is 6 years old, so it's very likely those instructions could be rendered out of date by new versions of the toolchains/IDE.

It doesn't actually matter what your .c file is called. As long as you have a main() function to enter. Using the "main.c" it gives you should be fine.

I would also recommend using XC16 if possible. C30 is no longer updated and is now considered legacy

Answer (score 1):

Use these code examples and user guides to get started with the 16-bit PIC devices.

MPLAB® XC16 User's Guide for Embedded Engineers: http://www.microchip.com/mymicrochip/filehandler.aspx?ddocname=en584558

MPLAB® XC16 User's Guide for Embedded Engineers Code Example: http://www.microchip.com/mymicrochip/filehandler.aspx?ddocname=en584564